# django queryset include more columns in select statement

Tags: python, django, orm, django-models, django-queryset

I been trying to create a backward relation using queryset and the joining is working fine, accept that its not including the other joined table in the selected columns. Below is my models, queryset and query.**str**() print

```
class Main(models.Model):
    slug       = models.SlugField()
    is_active  = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    site       = models.ForeignKey(Site)
    parent     = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, limit_choices_to={'parent' : None})
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("slug", "parent"))
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.slug

class MainI18n(models.Model):
    main                = models.ForeignKey(Main)
    language            = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=settings.LANGUAGES)
    title               = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    label               = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    description         = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    disclaimer          = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("language", "main"))
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
class List(models.Model):
    main        = models.ForeignKey(Main)
    slug        = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    is_active   = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    parent      = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.slug
class ListI18n(models.Model):
    list        = models.ForeignKey(List)
    language    = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=settings.LANGUAGES)
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("language", "list"))
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

and my queryset is

```
Main.objects.select_related('main', 'parent').filter(list__is_active=True, maini18n__language='en', list__listi18n__language='en')
```

and this is what my query is printing

```
'SELECT `category_main`.`id`, `category_main`.`slug`, `category_main`.`is_active`, `category_main`.`site_id`, `category_main`.`parent_id`, T5.`id`, T5.`slug`, T5.`is_active`, T5.`site_id`, T5.`parent_id` FROM `category_main` INNER JOIN `category_maini18n` ON (`category_main`.`id` = `category_maini18n`.`main_id`) INNER JOIN `category_list` ON (`category_main`.`id` = `category_list`.`main_id`) INNER JOIN `category_listi18n` ON (`category_list`.`id` = `category_listi18n`.`list_id`) LEFT OUTER JOIN `category_main` T5 ON (`category_main`.`parent_id` = T5.`id`) WHERE (`category_maini18n`.`language` = en  AND `category_list`.`is_active` = True  AND `category_listi18n`.`language` = en )'
```

anyone can help show columns from list and listi18n? I tried extra but It doesn't allow me to pass things like category_list.*

thanks

**UPDATE**

Thanks for Daniel approach, I managed to get it to work but instead I had to start from ListI18n

```
ListI18n.objects.select_related('list', 'list__main', 'list__main__parent', 'list__main__i18nmain').filter(list__is_active=True, list__main__maini18n__language='en', language='en').query.__str__()
```

Its working perfectly now, but I couldn't include list_*main*_maini18n, below is the output query

```
'SELECT `category_listi18n`.`id`, `category_listi18n`.`list_id`, `category_listi18n`.`language`, `category_listi18n`.`title`, `category_listi18n`.`description`, `category_list`.`id`, `category_list`.`main_id`, `category_list`.`slug`, `category_list`.`is_active`, `category_list`.`parent_id`, `category_main`.`id`, `category_main`.`slug`, `category_main`.`is_active`, `category_main`.`site_id`, `category_main`.`parent_id`, T5.`id`, T5.`slug`, T5.`is_active`, T5.`site_id`, T5.`parent_id` FROM `category_listi18n` INNER JOIN `category_list` ON (`category_listi18n`.`list_id` = `category_list`.`id`) INNER JOIN `category_main` ON (`category_list`.`main_id` = `category_main`.`id`) INNER JOIN `category_maini18n` ON (`category_main`.`id` = `category_maini18n`.`main_id`) LEFT OUTER JOIN `category_main` T5 ON (`category_main`.`parent_id` = T5.`id`) WHERE (`category_list`.`is_active` = True  AND `category_listi18n`.`language` = en  AND `category_maini18n`.`language` = en )'
```

Any idea how can I include MainI18n in the query result? should I use extra and include the tables and do the relation in the where clause? or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2):

The relationship from Main to List is a backwards ForeignKey (ie the FK is on List pointing at Main), and `select_related` doesn't work that way. When you think about it, this is correct: there are many Lists for each Main, so it doesn't make sense to say "give me the one List for this Main", which is what `select_related` is all about.

If you started from List, it would work:

```
List.objects.select_related('main__parent').filter(is_active=True, main__maini18n__language='en', listi18n__language='en')
```

because that way you're only following forwards relationships. You may find you're able to reorder your views/templates to use the query this way round.

Comment: Daniel, thanks mate for your suggestion, I tried your approach and it works perfectly. I faced another problem though, I cannot include MainI18n since its backward relation. I updated my post with a new queryset and its result, do you think there might be a better way to do it?

Comment: I never tried using managers, but would creating a model manager help? thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me it is actually working (`T5` in your select statement). You can always access fields from related instances in django via something like `my_obj.parent.is_active`. If you used `select_related` before they are included in the first query. If you didn't specify it in `select_related` a call to `my_obj.parent.is_active` for example would perform an extra db query.

Comment: yeah, you are right, its working for parent fields. but am also joining the List model which is not being included in the select statement. Its being joined in from and where clause but cannot get it to appear in the select statement.