# django model cannot access parent child record

Tags: django, orm, django-models, django-queryset

I have a very strange problem, I have a queryset that join with itself, when I try to access the parent record information using a[n] it works, when I loop through it doesn't. Does that make sense? below is my example

```
>>> a=Main.objects.select_related('main', 'parent').filter(list__is_active=True, maini18n__language='en', list__listi18n__language='en')
>>> a[10]._parent_cache.id
2L
>>> for i in a:
...  print i._parent_cache.id
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no mystery here. Not all the objects have a parent: item 10 does, but some (including the first) don't. You may want to check `i.parent_id` before accessing the related item.

Also, note that `_parent_cache` is an implementation detail: you should really be accessing the related objects via `i.parent`.

Comment: excellent explanation, I just tried it out and worked perfectly :)

Comment: i posted another question here http://stackoverflow.com/q/5889751/145277 about including inner joined table in the select statement. I would appreciate if you can help me out on that, you seem to know your way with django-models very well...